# Can't get dimensions of arrays equal to plot with MatPlotLib

Tags: matplotlib, dimensions

I am trying to create a plot of arrays where one is calculated based on my x-axis calculated in a for loop. I've gone through my code multiple times and tested in between what exactly the lengths are for my arrays, but I can't seem to think of a solution that makes them equal length.

This is the code I have started with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = 1 ;b = 2 ;c = 3; d = 1; e = 2
t0 = 0
t_end = 10
dt = 0.05
t = np.arange(t0, t_end, dt)
n = len(t)
fout = 1
M = 1


Ca = np.zeros(n)
Ca[0] = a; Cb[0] = b
Cc[0] = 0;
k1 = 1


def rA(Ca, Cb, Cc, t):
    -k1 * Ca**a * Cb**b * dt
    return -k1 * Ca**a * Cb**b * dt



while e > 1e-3:
    t = np.arange(t0, t_end, dt)
    n = len(t)
    for i in range(1,n-1):
        Ca[i+1] = Ca[i] + rA(Ca[i], Cb[i], Cc[i], t[i])
    e = abs((M-Ca[n-1])/M)
    M = Ca[n-1]
    dt = dt/2
    

    
plt.plot(t, Ca)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Afterwards, I try to calculate a second function for different y-values. Within the `for` loop I added:

```
Cb[i+1] = Cb[i] + rB(Ca[i], Cb[i], Cc[i], t[i])
```

While also defining `rB` in a similar manner as `rA`. The error code I received at this point is:

```
IndexError: index 200 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200
```

I feel like it has to do with the way I'm initializing the arrays for my `Ca`. To put it in MatLab code, something I'm more familiar with, looks like this in MatLab:
`Ca = zeros(1,n)`
I have recreated the code I have written here in MatLab and I do receive a plot. So I'm wondering where I am going wrong here?

So I thought my best course of action was to change n to an `int` by just changing it in the `while` loop.

but after changing `n = len(t)` to `n = 100` I received the following error message:
`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (200,) and (400,)`

As my previous question was something trivial I just kept on missing out on, I feel like this is the same. But I have spent over an hour looking and trying fixes without succes.

Comment: Your code uses `Cb` and `Cc`, which aren't defined.  Note that Python's indices go from 0 to n-1. So,  `Ca[0] = a` and `for i in range(0,n-1):  Ca[i+1] = Ca[i] + ...` seem more appropriate. Note that `range(0,n-1)` starts with 0 and has `n-2` as last value.

Comment: Thanks Johan, I have defined `Cb` and `Cc`. I messed up trying to create an MRE for better problem finding. Seems I missed out on adding that. Thanks for reminding me about the parameters of the range function.

Comment: Did you try changing the loop to `for i in range(0,n-1):  Ca[i+1] = Ca[i] + ...` (or to the equivallent `for i in range(1,n):  Ca[i] = Ca[i-1] + ...`)?